# Powdered Dipropylene Glycol Monomethyl Ether

Tags: solvents, cleaning

Entrepreneur here, background in electronics, so thank you in advance for your patience with me.

---

**Question:**

Is Dipropylene Glycol Monomethyl Ether available as a powder? If not, is there a powdered alternative?

**Application:**

My invention, for everyday people to use inside their homes on steel, plastic and aluminum, requires two liters of diluted liquid degreaser used at room temperature. On lay assumptions pertaining to design, logistics and safety, I am intent on offering this as powdered "just add water" degreaser. Dishwasher detergent does work, but a liquid degreaser sold by Harbor Freight Tools, diluted 50:1 works significantly better -and- it's MSDS describes overall threats on par with dishwasher detergent. It contains:

1. **Sodium MetaSilicate Pentahydrate** - readily available in powder form
2. **Tetrasodium EDTA** readily available in powder form
3. **Dipropylene Glycol Monomethyl Ether** Unable to find in powder form

I could not determine the constituent percentages. (sub-question: is there a way find this out?)

Comment: Its a liquid at room temp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Di(propylene_glycol)_methyl_ether

Comment: EDTA does not belong into municipal wastewater. Forbidden in houshold detergents > 1% in e.g. Switzerland.

Comment: Thanks Waylander and Karl. Environmental concerns are another key element - this degreaser must be able to be safely disposed of or neutralized then disposed of. International sales are hoped for, so thanks Karl for bringing it up. Thanks Waylander, I figured the powder question might be like asking for powdered water for room temperature use.